# access method in subclass

Tags: java

I have used the code:

```
//change size of raven
birdsByKey.get(instructions[0]).SizeRaven(newSize);
```

in order to try change the size of the raven.

What should I do to use the following method (in class "Raven")?

Comment: `if (raven instanceof Raven)` is *unnecessary*. You have `Raven raven = new Raven ();` .

Comment: `But it is not working! Everything else is fine with my program.` Define "not working"? If everything else is fine, then I assume it's a runtime error rather than compile time.

Comment: Not really, no; only use it when you're not sure what subclass you actually have.

Comment: This is a job for an abstract method: `Bird.changeSize()`, which you can call on any `Bird`, which is implemented by `Raven`, `Condor`, etc., as required. Using `instanceof` in a situation like this is poor design.

Answer (score 2):

`birdsByKey.get()` is going to return a `Bird`. A `Bird` won't have a `changeRavenSize()` method (since that is unique to a Raven).

You need something like:

```
Bird b = birdsByKey.get(instructions[0]);
if (b instanceof Raven) {
    Raven r = (Raven)b;
    r.changeSizeRaven(newSize);
}
```

As EJP mentions, you really want a `changeSize()` method for `Bird` which `Raven` will override. Then you code becomes

```
birdsByKey.get(instructions[0]).changeSize(newSize);
```

the first way you need to edit every time you add a new type of bird. The second way just add as many birds as you like and it'll just keep working...